# Unknown Uncaught Type Error in Jquery/ASP

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I need the submit button to check the null status of a radio box while being concatenated with asp to include an asp counter variable. A big red flag to me is that this code is displaying on the page as raw text, as if it were dropping the script tags completely from the code. If the 4th line of code is commented out, it wont display as such.

So far, I've built up this snip of code but it is not firing when the submit button is pressed.

```
<%
TmpString = ""
TmpString = TmpString & "<script type=" & chr(34) & "text/javascript" & chr(34) & ">"

TmpString = TmpString &"$(document).ready(function() {" 
    TmpString = "$(document).submit(function() {"
    TmpString = TmpString & chr(10) & chr(13)
        For z = 0 to TotalUnits -1
            TmpString = TmpString & "var genericValue" & z & "= document.getElementsByName(" & chr(34) & "checkbox" & z & chr(34) & ").value;"
            TmpString = TmpString & chr(10) & chr(13)
            TmpString = TmpString & "If genericValue" & z & " == Null {"
            TmpString = TmpString & chr(10) & chr(13)
                TmpString = TmpString & "alert(" & chr(34) & "Select Yes or No for checkbox" & chr(34) & ") };" 
                TmpString = TmpString & chr(10) & chr(13)
            TmpString = TmpString & "return; });"
            TmpString = TmpString & chr(10) & chr(13)
        Next
            TmpString = TmpString &"$(" & chr(34) & "button" & chr(34) & ").click(function() {"
            TmpString = TmpString & chr(10) & chr(13)
            TmpString = TmpString & "$(" & chr(34) & "formID" & chr(34) & ").submit() }); });"
            TmpString = TmpString & chr(10) & chr(13)
        TmpString = TmpString & "</script>"
Response.Write (TmpString)
%>
```

'checkradio HTML

```
                TmpString = TmpString & "<label id=" & chr(34) & "checklabel" & chr(34)
                TmpString = TmpString & " name=" & chr(34) & "checklabel" & chr(34)
                TmpString = TmpString & ">The Vehicle Requires Repair</label>"


                TmpString = TmpString & "<label id=" & chr(34) & "yesno" & chr(34) & ">"
                TmpString = TmpString & "<input type=" & chr(34) & "radio" & chr(34) & "name=" & chr(34) & "checkradio" & z & chr(34)
                TmpString = TmpString & "value=" & chr(34) & "1" & chr(34) & "id=" & chr(34) & "Radio1" & chr(34) & ">Yes</label>"
                TmpString = TmpString & "<label id=" & chr(34) & "yesno" & chr(34) & ">"
                TmpString = TmpString & "<input type=" & chr(34) & "radio" & chr(34) & "name=" & chr(34) & "checkradio" & z & chr(34)
                TmpString = TmpString & "value=" & chr(34) & "0" & chr(34) & "id=" & chr(34) & "Radio0" & chr(34) & ">No</label><br>"
```

This is the error I get in the browser's Console:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: Also, `"If genericValue" & z & " == Null {"` appears to be a strange mixture of VB.Net  and (invalid) C# being used as javascript, which isn't going to work... it would have to be `"if (genericValue" & z & " == null) {"`

Comment: The concatenation was from the last 20 people who worked on this site, believe me its been a pleasure to work with it like this.

Comment: Another hint is that VB.Net, you can escape a double-quote by simply doing two double-quotes.  E.g. instead of ` "$(" & chr(34) & "button" & chr(34)`... you can have `"$(""button""`

Comment: Why should the variable be placed in parenthesis? The code is ASP.net, to use TmpString & z. variable z is used in a for loop for counting.

Comment: There is no Visual basic .net in here as far as i am aware.

Comment: Why? Because the string you're sending to the browser is supposed to be javascript. And secondly, there is no such thing as ASP.Net "code"... it's VB.Net, or C#, or F#, etc.  The `TmpString = TmpString &` leads me to believe it's VB.Net

Comment: Ahh i understand. The scripting language they're using is very unfamiliar and strange IMO however until we set up a new server and remake everything in JSP, I need to keep moving forward this. Also im using the Jquery lib with Javascript, if that helps any.

Comment: Looks like VBScript (Classic ASP) - is this running on IIS? If active server pages are supported then it should load fine. Is this the whole page? Can you show all of it?

Comment: Yes...is this actually ASP Classic rather than ASP.NET? Looks like it might be.

Comment: I couldn't show the whole page unless i took all weekend to sanitize the sensitive information. It is running on IIS, and yes it is VBScript (I now realize).

Comment: It renders as `'$(document).submit(function() { $("button").click(function() { $("formID").submit() }); }); </script>`. So `TmpString` is overwritten multiple times.

Comment: @ADyson, how can I check, there are no import statements.

Comment: @rustycodecs file extension and general folder structure would be the easiest. The file you're editing, does it have a .asp extension? or .aspx? Or something else?

Comment: Anyway what are the values of `TotalUnits` and `z`? They're the only bits which seem to cause the final output content to be varied. There is almost certainly an easier way to do this. Getting rid of all the pointless calls to `chr` would make it instantly more readable. The browser doesn't care whether you have line breaks in your JS or not

Comment: @ADyson this page is a .asp, TotalUnits change depending on how many vehicles a user must inspect. z is used with a for loop to keep count of these, as well as dynamically generate new tables with checkboxes for the inspection.

Comment: @rustycodecs it's [ASP Classic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524741(v%3Dvs.90)) then, nothing to do with .NET. I updated the tags. The answer below is probably the simplest solution then. Much, much easier to deal with. Although I suspect you could use jQuery selectors to make that validation code more efficient and not need the `z` or `TotalUnits` at all (and could therefore do the whole thing as a static JavaScript block, without any injection of code generated by the VB). Would depend a bit on the structure of the related HTML though, which we can't see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're getting errors in your console because the javascript you're sending to the browser is simply invalid.

The code you've presented is (quite simply) awful, and therefore it's not easy to see the javascript errors that the code will produce...

- `If genericValue1 == Null {` will never work as javascript.
- `$("formID").submit();` won't work because you need `#` before the ID

As you've stated that this is classic ASP, it could be written as following...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(document).submit(function() {
      <%For z = 0 to TotalUnits - 1%>
      var genericValue<%=z%> = document.getElementsByName("checkbox<%=z%>").value;
      if (genericValue<%=z%> == null) {
        alert("Select Yes or No for checkbox <%=z%>");
        return false;
      }
      <%Next%>
      $("button").click(function() {
        $("#formID").submit();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Which I hope you can see is far easier to read and understand

Comment: Your For loop should be closed with a Next, not End If, looks good to me otherwise. Aside from the mild trauma of forcibly reading VBScript injected javascript, of course

Comment: Fair comment @mjw - typing too quickly as per usual ;-)

Comment: You're welcome @rusty - good luck with the rest of your project. Which on that evidence will not be easy! ;-)

Comment: @rusty - As ADyson said in their comment under your question, there is definitely improvements you can make using jquery without the need for any inline code or the `z` variable

Comment: @freefaller The page pops the notification whether the radio is yes, no, or null. Do you have any insight into why this is happening?

Comment: @rusty - radio buttons are individual controls, which all need unique id's but should share the same `name` (which is how they link together)... you need to get all those items using `document.getElementsByName()` and check each of the items in he array it returns

Comment: @freefaller The id's are unique and the names are the same. Line 5 of what you posted is what i thought checked the items in the array. z increments up through each iteration, checking for nulls(?). I need the block to run for each vehicle, which each generate their own inspection table. Every inspection table will have a radio at the bottom that cannot be null when submitted. Do I need to add Else If statements to handle returning "0" or "1" (Boolean logic tied to radio values)

Comment: @rustycodecs post (a sample of) the HTML and it'll be much easier to help with this. Potentially it should be a new question actually, since it's somewhat drifted away from what you originally asked.

Comment: @ADyson Okay but, you asked for it

Comment: @rusty - I agree with ADyson - it should really be a new question. Your original question has been solved, best create a new one

Comment: @freefaller My mistake

Comment: @rustycodecs Agreed. New question please, since it's basically a new and different problem. Link to it here and tag us, and we'll happily look at it for you. Thanks.

Comment: @rusty - not a problem, SO can be a learning curve in itself :-)

Comment: @freefaller @ ADyson [New Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58454746/javascript-function-to-send-alert-firing-regardless-of-value-returned) I hope this is how you meant to link and tag you guys