# Javascript function to send alert firing regardless of value returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic

The function created to send an alert based on a radio box's value returning as null is firing and sending alert while radio box has a value that should not be null. Somewhere else on the page is a function that hides the tables these radios appear on, and is what initially made this task out of my reach. If this div didn't hide, and these tables weren't generated dynamically then it could have been solved by adding a required attribute to the radio. This actually works as long as the div is showing, however breaks when hidden. I've essentially been tasked to take the long way around making this radio required.

Here is the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function validate() {
$(document).submit(function() {
  <%For z = 0 to TotalUnits - 1%>
  if ($("input[name='checkradio<%=z%>']:checked").length == 0)
    alert("Select Yes or No for Needs Repair checkbox <%=z%>");
    return false;
  }
  <%Next%>
  $("submitbutton").click(function() {
    $("#formID").submit();
document.getElementsByName("checkradio").addEventListener('click', 
validate);  
});
});
});
</script>
```

Here is the HTML

```
<label id="checklabel" name="checklabel">The Vehicle Requires Repair</label>"


<label id="yesradio">
<input type="radio" ((name="checkradio" & z)) value="1" id="Radio1"> Yes</label>
<label id="noradio">
<input type="radio" ((name="checkradio" & z)) value="0" id="Radio0"> No</label>
```

Here is the script that hides the div (I cleaned the concat. but left the meat in its own tags)

```
<script>

<%for z = 0 to TotalUnits - 1%>

    $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("div.section<%=z%>").hide();
    });


<%next%>

</script>
<%response.write(TmpString)%>
```

Here is my submit button (stripped off the label)

```
<input value="Submit" type="submit" id="submitbutton" name="submitbutton" 
onsubmit="validate()">
```

The alert should only fire when the submit button is pressed and the value of the radio is null.

Comment: it would be far, far easier if you could put the rendered HTML that is sent to the browser, rather than the (as you admit) horrible code?

Comment: @freefaller sorry, I'm trying to get this solved while doing my help desk duties as well. Neither me nor the guy above me claim to know JS, however when I tried adding an event listener, naming the function, and calling it with onsubmit in the submit button it broke to the point of not firing at all\

Comment: You are assigning the submit method on the document itself.  Could that be it?

Comment: @dev4life no that has nothing at all to do with it. The incorrect use of getElementsByName is the issue. See freefaller's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Because each radio button is a control it is own right, you need to check if any of the controls that are linked together (via the `name` attribute) are checked.

Firstly, `getElementsByName()` returns an array (notice the `s` on `Elements`), so there is no `.value` for you to check.

(Oh, and be aware that having multiple `<label id="yesno">` is invalid, as elements need to have a unique `id` attribute. In this case you're probably best just removing the `id="yesno"` completely.)

But it's a lot, lot easier to do this via jQuery...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $(document).submit(function() {
      <%For z = 0 to TotalUnits - 1%>
      if ($("input[name='checkradio<%=z%>']:checked").length == 0)
        alert("Select Yes or No for Needs Repair checkbox <%=z%>");
        return false;
      }
      <%Next%>
      $("submitbutton").click(function() {
        $("#formDVIR").submit();
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

By using the selector of `input[name='checkradio<%=z%>']:checked` you're asking jQuery to find all input controls with a name of `checkradio1` (or whatever `z` is) and only those which are `checked`. If the length of the resultant jQuery object is more than 1 you know at least one is selected

Comment: It feels like you only used jQuery for selecting elements and adding event listeners. Then you might as well cut out the library and use querySelector and addEventListener.

Comment: @somethinghere - the OP is using jQuery in other parts of their code... it's not purely the selector

Comment: @freefaller this has been transplanted in and I will attempt to add an event handler shortly

Comment: @freefaller I've added the "event handler", however i'm unclear as to if it should be 'submit' instead of 'click'

Comment: @rusty - I've finished for the day, so writing this via phone. Remember that you need `#` in your jquery selector... `$("#submittbutton")`

Comment: @freefaller- Much appreciated

Answer (score -3):

push me or so

const myId=document.getElementById(“myId”);
myId.addEventListener(“click”, function () { alert(“message and stuff”)});

Comment: how does this solve anything which is being discussed in the question??